# Cannot select links in compound class, selenium, python3, css

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with Python3 and I am trying to select this element.

```
<a class="multilineClickable cw-ml-clickable-cell cw-ml-svc-desc" style="">Fw: Text - Additions for Text</a>
```

**Here is more code hopefully its a bit clearer as there is so much, I am trying to grab as much as I can to make this clear:**

```
<table class="GHN3134DKTE srboardmember-grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 4035px;">
<tbody>
<tbody>
<tr class="GHN3134DDUE cw-ml-row">
<td cellindex="0" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DND">
<td cellindex="1" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DMD">
<td cellindex="2" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DMD">
<td cellindex="3" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DMD">
<td cellindex="4" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="5" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="6" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DMD">
<td cellindex="7" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="8" class="GHN3134DETE">
<div class="GHN3134DGTE">
<a class="multilineClickable cw-ml-clickable-cell cw-ml-svc-desc" style="">Text that will change</a>
</div>
</td>
<td cellindex="9" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DND">
<td cellindex="10" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DND">
<td cellindex="11" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="12" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="13" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="14" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="15" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="16" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="17" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="18" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="19" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="20" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="21" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DMD">
<td cellindex="22" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DMD">
<td cellindex="23" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DMD">
<td cellindex="24" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="25" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="26" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="27" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="28" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="29" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="30" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="31" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="32" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="33" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DMD">
<td cellindex="34" class="GHN3134DETE x-grid-td-GHN3134DMD">
<td cellindex="35" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="36" class="GHN3134DETE">
<td cellindex="37" class="GHN3134DETE">
</tr>
<tr class="GHN3134DDUE GHN3134DEUE cw-ml-row">
<tr class="GHN3134DDUE cw-ml-row">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**I use the below code:**

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("multilineClickable cw-ml-clickable-cell cw-ml-svc-desc"
```

**and get this Exception:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

I have tried the below css as this is how compound classes should be selected.

```
     driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".multilineClickable.cw-ml-clickable-cell cw-ml-svc-desc")
     driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".multilineClickable.cw-ml-clickable-cell.cw-ml-svc-desc")
```

**and get this Exception**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".multilineClickable.cw-ml-clickable-cell cw-ml-svc-desc"
```

But I am still getting my head around CSS, can someone please how me the right code?

I would have pasted all the code however its like 7 pages long so I have culled it.

The reason I am not selecting by XPath or partial link text, or link text is because the link text is going to change.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about this for css. Try this driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='multilineClickable cw-ml-clickable-cell cw-ml-svc-desc']")...   You can use xpath for the class name - "//a[@class='multilineClickable cw-ml-clickable-cell cw-ml-svc-desc']".

Comment: Thanks for your help grassphopper however still having some issues...

Exception:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[class='multilineClick‌​able cw-ml-clickable-cell cw-ml-svc-desc']"}`

Exception:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='multilineClickable cw-ml-clickable-cell cw-ml-svc-desc']"}`

Hopefully with the updated code it will make more sense.

Comment: This worked:
`links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='multilineClickable cw-ml-clickable-cell cw-ml-svc-desc']")`
`links[0].click()` Thanks grashopper!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some explicit wait to your script which will wait for the element to be loaded on the page. Try the below code,

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS, "a.multilineClickable")));
driver.find_element_by_css("a.multilineClickable").click();
```

Comment: Hi Sudarshan, i got this exception:

tried:
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.multilineClickable").click()`

exception:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.multilineClickable"}`